# Many-to-one prediction using LSTM in Keras, reshaping data

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have multiple **pandas dataframes** containing multiple users, with for each user, a sequence of sequential timestamps of multiple features. It looks something like the following:

```
      user    day    feature_1    ...    feature_n
0     1       0      6            ...    5        
1     1       1      7            ...    4       
2     1       2      6            ...    7       
3     1       3      7            ...    8     
4     1       4      6            ...    4    
5     1       5      4            ...    3    
6     1       6      3            ...    5   
7     1       7      4            ...    6    
8     1       8      3            ...    7    
9     1       9      4            ...    7
10    2       0      3            ...    5
11    2       1      5            ...    4
```

**I want to predict the value of feature_1, one timestamp ahead, given seven timestamps of information, per user: many-to-one prediction if I am correct.**

I have previously clustered my users and want to create **one LSTM model per dataframe.**
I've already filtered out users with less than 8 timestamps and I know how to create a target per row using the *groupby* and *shift* functions in *pandas*.

The Keras LSTM implementation requires data in the format of a 3D tensor and gives the following help in the documentation: **[nSamples, nTimesteps, nFeatures]**

I do not understand how I should achieve this, given my dataset and goal. I have tried searching for solutions or tutorials but have been unable to find any so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If it matters, I am using Python 3.6.6, Keras 2.2.4, Tensorflow 1.11.0 and numpy 1.15.2

**EDIT:** Thanks to the suggestion from @ely I managed to figure it out. I should create a sample for every 7 timestamps as he explains in his comment. However, the most pythonic way of achieving this I still have not figured out.

Comment: This may be a helpful link, https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/ You basically want to reshape your data in the printed format from your question so that in a new `numpy.ndarray` (say it is called `x`) you would have `x[0, :, :]` = rows 0 to 6, columns `feature_1` to `feature_n`, and `x[1, :, :]` = rows 1 to 7, columns `feature_1` to `feature_n`, and so on. ALso don't forget you need to align the seventh row `feature_1` as the training label `y[0]`, and the eighth row `feature_1` as the training label `y[1]`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Too bad I cannot mark a comment as a solution. Then again, I still have to think of an efficient pythonic way of achieving this result.

Comment: A good way to do this efficiently is to just use a generator and a simple loop over your existing data structure. This way you do not have to actually materialize the rolling sequential version anywhere in memory and you can express the logic with a clean, simple for-loop instead of a needless code golf sort of vectorized operation in pandas or numpy. Keras provides ways to consume training samples sequentially from a generator as well, so it's actually one of the preferred ways to do it. Sort of like streaming your examples for training.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @ely. I think I can achieve this with the TimeSeriesGenerator from the keras model.preprocessing class [link](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/). Would this mean I have to create multiple generators, one per user per dataset?